# ZeroMQ and multiple subscribe filters in Python

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

I'd like to subscribe to multiple filters with ZeroMQ in Python, using one socket.

```
sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'first.filter')
sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'second.filter')
```

But this doesn't work. Only the first one is taken in account. However, I read this on [zeromq site](http://api.zeromq.org/2-2:zmq-setsockopt):

> Multiple filters may be attached to a single `ZMQ_SUB` socket, in which case a message shall be accepted if it matches at least one filter.

I'm using zmq 2.2.0.1. So, I wonder how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works:

```
import time
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()
pub = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
sub = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)

url = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555"
pub.bind(url)
sub.connect(url)

# subscribe to 'a' and 'b'
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'a')
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'b')

time.sleep(1)

for word in [ 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'apple', 'carrot', 'bagel']:
    pub.send(word)

time.sleep(1)

for i in range(4):
    print sub.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK)
```

gives output:

```
alpha
beta
apple
bagel
```

So both subscriptions do work.  What's your exact code? Because maybe it's another issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Indeed this works, in my case I'm using a forwarder device between publisher and subscriber. Disabling it makes things work... still investigating why forwarder device prevents from having multiple filters...

Comment: Ok I reply to myself my code is a little bit complicated and I messed up somewhere. Works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: What if you wanted to know which if the filters was caught when receiving. For instance whether you received for topic a, or b ? I am using jeromq though

Comment: @Marc I have exactly the same problem. I also have an XPUB and XSUB between my Publisher and Subscriber. When I subscribe to multiple topics on the subscriber, I only get the messages for the first topic. How could you solve your problem? Did you just remove the proxy?