# Topics in ZeroMQ

Tags: zeromq

How better to separate topics using ZeroMQ - just by specifying different ports or by using prefixes like here: [ZeroMQ and multiple subscribe filters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904626/zeromq-and-multiple-subscribe-filters-in-python)

It looks simpler to specify ports.

I do not mean to connect to multiple topics. I mean that different parts of application will connect to different ports.

Answer (score 0):

### No, using different port numbers will not work the way you feel.

```
aSubTypeSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, aLeftMatchTopicFILTERasSTRING )
aSubTypeSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE,    anotherTopicFILTERasSTRING )
...
aSubTypeSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.UNSUBSCRIBE, aLeftMatchTopicFILTERasSTRING )
...
aSubTypeSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, yetAnotherTopicFILTERasSTRING )
```

is the standard mechanism how to setup Topic-filter matching condition(s) to effectively work with.

---

### Multiple `connect()`-s are possible, but

```
aSubTypeSOCKET.connect( "tcp://123.123.123.123:12345" )
aSubTypeSOCKET.connect( "tcp://123.123.123.123:23456" )
aSubTypeSOCKET.connect( "tcp://123.123.123.123:34567" )
```

will make `aSubTypeSOCKET` indeed `.connect()`-ed to several port-numbers, but the sender side yet decides, if a subscription "mechanics" will deliver a content "specialisation" that you might have expected to use instead of the common Topic-filter(s) subscribed to using `.setsockopt()`.

Next, if multiple `.connect()`-ed **`PUB`**-s deliver messages, the **`SUB`**-side is getting these in through an incoming "routing" strategy, by a "**Fair-queue**d" manner, so the `SUB`-side will have to turn and check the round-robin wheel a complete turn around, just to see, if any present/not-present and any non-empty subscription Topic-filter setup will apply to all `PUB`-sides symmetrically, similarly the first empty-string Topic-filter will "unblock" / "short-cut" all senders to deliver any messages from all `PUB`-access-nodes.

I would not call that any simpler.

---

## APPs typically build a complex signalling/messaging plane

an indeed as persistent as possible infrastructure, where many socket-Access-Points do `.bind() / .connect()` to many individual access-point addresses, as desired for, using some mix of many transport-classes available **`{ inproc:// | ipc:// | tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | vmci:// }`**.

This is one of many strengths the designs, based on ZeroMQ, can and do enjoy.

Comment: I dont mean connection  to multiply topics. I mean that different parts of application will connect to different ports